# How to solve 'ImportError: Error importing 'settings': No module named 'basic'' in quepy dbpedia example

Tags: python, nlp

I have tried running quepy `dbpedia` main file but when calling quepy.install('dbpedia') even though setting.py is available in dbpedia folder it shows ImportError,,  The code and output as follows:

```
#"""
#Main script for DBpedia quepy.
#"""

import sys
import time
import random
import datetime

import quepy
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
dbpedia = quepy.install("dbpedia")
```

Output

```
-->dbpedia = quepy.install("dbpedia")
ImportError: Error importing 'settings': No module named 'basic'
```

Comment: check that you are using the correct sys.path

Comment: read the documentation here: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/quepy/latest/quepy.pdf